# Are there any 1980's video chips still available besides the TMS9918?

Tags: video, chip, tms9918

The TMS9918 is still available, which is nice.

But are there any other (better) video chips still on the (after-)market in any numbers? Obviously Commodore's VIC-II is not one of them.

Comment: Better, there's the 9958 - it might be as well be possible to still get hands on a 9990 :)) Also, I got the feeling this has already been answered.

Comment: @Raffzahn thanks, if it has already been answered perhaps there is a link. I could not find it when I searched.

Comment: _"The TMS9918 is still available"_ - where?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, check out eBay. Somehow there is a wellspring of them in China.

Comment: The Commodore VIC-II is also available on eBay: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Pulled-Working-MOS-8562R4-VIC-II-C64-Commodore-64-Chip-IC-OEM-US-SELLER-/254821399324

Comment: Thanks, now that we know what 'available' means we can make a list. I'm thinking of purchasing a few for my own collection (already have most of the 99xx variants, all obtained from eBay).

Comment: By the way, the VIC-II having shown up once on eBay is not exactly what I would call  "available".  Sure I can buy a C64, and I have 3 in my storage, and pull one off. That is not the same as the availability of TMS9918, which appears to be available in lots and bulks for not even very expensive. I just ordered a lot of 5 from China for less than 20 bucks.

Answer (score 8):

Since you seem to consider buying on ebay to qualify as available, I'd nominate the TI 34010 and 34020. Looks like you can pick them up for around $50-60 apiece (though quantity available may be open to question--most seemed to be lots of one).

There seem to be at least a few Intel 82876's available as well (for around the same price).

Comment: Wow! That's a class up right there, of historic importance I guess, seeing this crashed my thought-box. I was thinking DIP package video chip, this is a GPU. Very good mention because it extended my limited horizon. Thanks.